# Ionic 3 Status bar color in splash screen (android)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I have added the following 2 lines in my config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashStatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#488aff" />
<preference name="SplashScreenSpinnerColor" value="#488aff" />
```

The `SplashStatusBarBackgroundColor` works when plugin is installed form https://github.com/goinnn/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git#4.0.0#colors

However, `SplashScreenSpinnerColor` color does not change.

When the splash plugin is updated to the latest version `SplashScreenSpinnerColor` changes perfectly but `SplashStatusBarBackgroundColor` does not change now. How can i get them both working?